# Calling C++ Static Library from D

Tags: c++, visual-studio, d

I am trying to call a c++ function from a D module. I have followed the guide on this page http://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html but I am unable to get it to work.

I have created a solution in visual studio 2015 with two projects in it, one is the D project and the other is C++ project. I build the C++ project and generate a .lib file. Then in the D project I have set the path to the lib file in Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Library Files but when I run the solution I get Error43: Not a Valid Library File.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support D out of the box, are you using some plugin? And what D compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual D 0.3.43 and dmd 2.069.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that your library contains [COFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) object files, but DMD expects them to be in the [OMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocatable_Object_Module_Format) format. (Take a look at "Can I link in C object files created with another compiler?" @ https://dlang.org/faq.html)

What you have to do is to convert the library to OMF for use with DMD using, say, [coff2omf tool](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/coff2omf.html). This tool is part of the DigitalMars extension package (check the [freecompiler download](http://www.digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html) section) Or, if you can, use some C++ compiler, like DigitalMars C/C++ compiler, to generate an OMF library.

Also, take a look at: [Converting COFF lib file to OMF format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114339/converting-coff-lib-file-to-omf-format)

Comment: do you have a link to the tool? i cant seem to find a way to download it anywhere

Comment: dmd for win32 can output coff since several monthes now (switch __-ms32coff__), which you can do instead of converting. Another option is to make a dynamic library in c++.